# Change amount using jQuery UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yesterday I tried to make a slider that will increase and decrease amount when sliding. It all works fine with ONE ingredient.

[`jsFiddle.1`](http://jsfiddle.net/superior/bUq38/3/)

Code:

```
 var defaultNumber = +($('.amount').text()); // Get default value of recipe for 8 persons
$('#slider').slider({   
  min: 1,
  max: 12,
  value: 8,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('.portionsChange').text(ui.value); // PORTIONS  

            $('.ingredient p').each(function(index, elem) { // Recalculate each ingredient amount
              console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );

                var amount = $('.amount', elem);
            var number = +($('.amount').text()); // Get current value of the recipe
            var singleAmount = $('.amount').attr('data-single', parseFloat(defaultNumber*0.125)); // Add "data-single" to every recipe according to the defaultNumber of 8 persons
                var serve = ui.value * parseFloat(amount.data('single')); // Value of portions * original recipe

                amount.text(Math.round(serve * 100) / 100); // Round to 2 decimals
            });
    }
    });
```

However, when I try to add more ingredients they will all just sum up and become the same amount.

How can I solve this?

[`jsFiddle.2`](http://jsfiddle.net/superior/bUq38/2/)

Comment: You need to provide some code before linking to jsfiddle. I editted your post so you can add the code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many fails and errors I decided to talk to a friend of mine. We (mostly him) coded a pure javascript version of what I wanted to achieve. I thought of posting it here for other people looking to do the same thing;

http://codepen.io/MaxHill/pen/CJAEl?editors=001